# Current screen bounding box in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a map that contains a lot of features that are added dynamically.

I want to detech the last added point if it is on the screen, or not.
And when it is, i want to play a short notofication sound.

Like this:

```
if (ol.extent.containsCoordinate(map.getExtent(), ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(data.lon), parseFloat(data.lat)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')))
{
  var audio = new Audio('tick.wav');
  audio.play();
}
```

But I cannot find any method to get the current bounding of the screen in the docs of OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, this is missing from the docs.

```
if (ol.extent.containsCoordinate(map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()), ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(data.lon), parseFloat(data.lat)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')))
{
  var audio = new Audio('tick.wav');
  audio.play();
}
```